# How do I minimize the command prompt from my bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have this `bat` file and I want to minimize the `cmd` window when I run it:

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\leads\ssh 
call C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat
ruby C:\leads\ssh\put_leads.rb
```

I want the command window minimized immediately. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 121):

There is a quite interesting way to execute script minimized by making him restart itself minimised. Here is the code to put in the beginning of your script:

```
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %* && exit
... script logic here ...
exit
```

#### How it works

When the script is being executed `IS_MINIMIZED` is not defined (`if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED`) so:

1. **IS_MINIMIZED** is set to **1**: `set IS_MINIMIZED=1`.
2. Script starts a copy of itself using **start** command  `&& start "" /min "%~dpnx0" %*` where:

   1. `""` - empty title for the window.
   2. `/min` - switch to run minimized.
   3. `"%~dpnx0"` - full path to your script.
   4. `%*` - passing through all your script's parameters.
3. Then initial script finishes its work: `&& exit`.

For the started copy of the script variable `IS_MINIMIZED` is set by the original script so it just skips the execution of the first line and goes directly to the script logic.

#### Remarks

- You have to reserve some variable name to use it as a flag.
- The script should be ended with `exit`, otherwise the cmd window wouldn't be closed after the script execution.
- If your script doesn't accept arguments you could use argument as a flag instead of variable:

  `if "%1" == "" start "" /min "%~dpnx0" MY_FLAG && exit`
  or shorter
  `if "%1" == "" start "" /min "%~f0" MY_FLAG && exit`

Comment: add "not", eq,   ->  if not DEFINED

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. A genuine typo!

Comment: thanks, good one! I wanted to kill a process when the user logs in, so I dropped a bat like this in the Startup folder without being too intrusive.

Comment: I used it for exactly the same purpose :) I was killing some annoying service that popped up on every login to server and I had no permissions to wipe it out from startup sequence.

Comment: reminds me of the exclusion guards in C. My first year CS professor had a project to show us the value of those guards.....

Comment: This helped me solve a very tricky problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175160/can-i-make-node-js-opn-open-the-browser-with-maximized-window-when-node-js-itsel/48204548#48204548. For some reason this works for my case. Thanks a lot for this one.

Comment: This works reasonably well for a scheduled task, though I'm unsure if the temporary console window can momentarily steal focus. So far so good...

Comment: does this forwards any arguments from the first batch? it didn't work for me that way? only getting:The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: `If your script doesn't accept arguments you could use argument as a flag instead of variable:` I don't understand this part at all, could someone please elaborate? How do you read the shorten code?

Comment: @Unknown123 the shorter version 1) skipped ```%*``` of original version, which passes any argument to the new window; 2) pass the flag ```MY_FLAG``` as argument to the new window;  and 3) checks for ```%1``` (the first argument to the script). 
In the parent window, %1 would be empty as the script does not accept arguments, so a daughter window would be started with an argument "MY_FLAG". The daughter window detects this argument and proceed with the scripts, without further spawning more windows.

Comment: @R.Wang I got it, `"if %1" == ""` means to check whether the arguments is empty, The name/content of `MY_FLAG` could be anything since it doesn't matter. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 60):

Use the `start` command, with the `/min` switch to run minimized. For example:

```
start /min C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat
```

Since you've specified a batch file as the argument, the command processor is run, passing the `/k` switch. This means that the window will remain on screen after the command has finished. You can alter that behavior by explicitly running `cmd.exe` yourself and passing the appropriate switches if necessary.

Alternatively, you can create a shortcut to the batch file (are PIF files still around), and then alter its properties so that it starts minimized.

Comment: i tried this and it does hide the cmd window but it doesnt run the next line ruby C:\leads\ssh\put_leads.rb

Comment: @Tamer: No, of course it doesn't. It only runs the command specified as an argument to the `start` command. Put all of the commands inside of the batch file, or call `start` multiple times.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this with a scheduled task. The scheduled tasks does not seem to recognize the "start" as a valid command.

Comment: @macetw How about putting that in another batch file?

Answer (score 28):

Using PowerShell you can minimize from the same file without opening a new instance.

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
```

Also `-window hidden` and `-window normal` is available to hide completely or restore.

---

*source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061676/1178975*

Comment: Powershell introduce delays. Any idea to make it faster?

Comment: Oh wow, the hidden window is amazing! Can't do that with a Windows shortcut.

Comment: This saved me, thanks! I wanted to unlock a bitlocker container, then launch an app and lock it after the app is closed. So a bat file run as admin asks for container password, then runs second batch using your PS that starts an encrypted app and waits for it to finish to relock. And unlike other tools it passes the elevated privileges to the second batch to properly lock.

Answer (score 26):

The only way I know is by creating a Windows shortcut to the batch file and then changing its properties to run minimized by default.

Comment: Was a lot easier than expected.

Comment: i agree with dennis' comment. as  they say, 'keep it simple sam'. no code needed, no sweat

Comment: the hack, thanks mate much easier steps :)

Comment: simplest solution

Answer (score 8):

If you want to start the batch for Win-Run / autostart, I found I nice solution here https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000932.htm & https://superuser.com/questions/364799/how-to-run-the-command-prompt-minimized

```
cmd.exe /c start /min myfile.bat ^& exit
```

- the `cmd.exe` is needed as start is no windows command that can be executed outside a batch
- `/c` = exit after the start is finished
- the `^& exit` part ensures that the window closes even if the batch does not end with `exit`

However, the initial cmd is still not minimized.

Comment: Only way that worked for me to start a batch file minimized via Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: As @BusinessTomcat said, this is the only one that seems to work properly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

One way to 'minimise' the cmd window is to reduce the size of the console using something like...

```
echo DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW
MODE CON COLS=30 LINES=2
```

You can reduce the COLS to about 18 and the LINES to 1 if you wish.
The advantage is that it works under WinPE, 32-bit or 64-bit, and does not require any 3rd party utility.

Answer (score 4):

If you type this text in your bat file:

```
start /min blah.exe
```

It will immediately minimize as soon as it opens the program. You will only see a brief flash of it and it will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for you contribution, but this is the same approach as the highest voted answer.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to find one of the various utilities that can change the window state of the currently running console window and make a call to it from within the batch script.

You can run it as the first thing in your batch script. Here are two such tools:

min.exe
http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cmdprogs.htm

cmdow
http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/index.html

Comment: I usually like to use `nircmdc.exe` for stuff like this but for some reason it wouldn't minimize the active window when it was a console window.  However, `cmdow` worked great!  `cmdow @ /min` was how I did it, where `@` is how to indicate that you want to target the active window.  (I'm in Windows 10.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a script as follows

```
var WindowStyle_Hidden = 0
var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
var result = objShell.Run("cmd.exe /c setrbvars.bat", WindowStyle_Hidden)
```

save the file as filename.js

Comment: The request is to hide the command prompt from a *batch file*, not make a javascript to run elsewhere that runs something else which finally hides it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another free 3rd party tool that is capable of minimizing the console window at any time (not only when starting the script) is Tcl with the TWAPI extension:

```
echo package require twapi;twapi::minimize_window [twapi::get_console_window] | tclkitsh -
```

here `tclkitsh.exe` is in the PATH and is one of the `tclkit-cli-*-twapi-*.exe` files downloadable from [sourceforge.net/projects/twapi/files/Tcl binaries/Tclkits with TWAPI/](https://sourceforge.net/projects/twapi/files/Tcl%20binaries/Tclkits%20with%20TWAPI/). I prefer it to the much lighter `min.exe` mentioned in [Bernard Chen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148970) because I use TWAPI for countless other purposes already.

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize the command prompt on during the run but you'll need two additional scripts: [***windowMode***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat) and [***getCmdPid.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat):

```
@echo off

call getCmdPid
call windowMode -pid %errorlevel% -mode minimized

cd /d C:\leads\ssh 
call C:\Ruby192\bin\setrbvars.bat
ruby C:\leads\ssh\put_leads.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works fine for me is to use ConEmu, see http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html

```
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" -min -run myfile.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
CONSOLESTATE /Min
```

or:

```
SETCONSOLE /minimize
```

or:

```
TITLE MinimizeMePlease
FOR /F %%A IN ('CMDOW ˆ| FIND "MinimizeMePlease"') DO CMDOW %%A /MIN
```

Answer (score 0):

http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html download flagged by Virus Total.
May have Malware.