# How to use call to execute others cmd file with maximized window?

Tags: batch-file

I have to use `"call"` to execute other cmd file. I want to maximized the window. I tried this but it still not working.

```
call /MAX %~dp0\test.cmd
```

Anyone can help, really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `call` has no `/max` switch (`start` has...)

Comment: @Stephan it means I can not use call to maximized the window?

Comment: you want to maximize the current window?

Comment: Would be nice if you could talk a program into doing what you like it to do... alas I think you have to stick to the syntax it provides => `call /?`, `start /?`

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060156/388389

Comment: `call` doesn't do anything to the "environment" (terminal/window). (that's not what it's built for)

Comment: Thank you @npocmaka, this solution  stackoverflow.com/a/45060156/388389 work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is working.

```
powershell -windowstyle maximized -command ""
call %~dp0\test.cmd
```

Reference from this :  stackoverflow.com/a/45060156/388389